# Create a method like Devise's current_user to use everywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I'm allowing my users to have multiple profiles (user has many profiles) and one of them is the default. In my users table I have a default_profile_id.

How do I create a "default_profile" like Devise's current_user which I can use everywhere?

Where should I put this line?

```
default_profile = Profile.find(current_user.default_profile_id)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Devise's current_user method looks like this:

```
def current_#{mapping}
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :#{mapping})
end
```

As you can see, the `@current_#{mapping}` is being memoized. In your case you'd want to use something like this:

```
def default_profile
  @default_profile ||= Profile.find(current_user.default_profile_id)
end
```

Regarding using it everywhere, I'm going to assume you want to use it both in your controllers and in your views. If that's the case you would declare it in your ApplicationController like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :default_profile

  def default_profile
    @default_profile ||= Profile.find(current_user.default_profile_id)
  end
end
```

The `helper_method` will allow you to access this memoized default_profile in your views. Having this method in the `ApplicationController` allows you to call it from your other controllers.

Answer (score 3):

You can put this code inside application controller by defining inside a method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  helper_method :default_profile

  def default_profile 
    Profile.find(current_user.default_profile_id)
  rescue
    nil 
  end
  ... 
end
```

And, can access it like current_user in your application. If you call default_profile, it will give you the profile record if available, otherwise nil.

Comment: I'd actually put that in the User model.

Comment: `rescue nil` is a bad pattern. `find_by_id(...)` returns also `nil` if nothing found.

Comment: I'm getting NameError: undefined local variable or method `default_persona' for main:Object

Comment: @AenTan: just define: helper_method :default_profile, updated answer also.

Comment: Thanks for all the time but it was really AdamT's answer that really helped and was also informational at the same time. But thanks really.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method `profile` to user or define a `has_one` (preferred). Than it is just `current_user.profile` if you want the default profile:

```
has_many :profiles
has_one  :profile  # aka the default profile
```

I would not implement the shortcut method, but you want:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def default_profile
    current_user.profile
  end
  helper_method :default_profile

end
```